# Several errors while runninv mvn clean verify

Tags: bash, maven, redhat, amq

Idk whats wrong, i just wanna run an amq-broker example...Here's my full settings.xml (i just added the jboss-amq-maven-repository PROFILE & also added jboss-amq-maven-repository as my activeprofile, the rest is completely default...).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->

  <!-- interactiveMode
   | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set to false,
   | maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some other setting, for
   | the parameter in question.
   |
   | Default: true
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  -->

  <!-- offline
   | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing a build.
   | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.
   |
   | Default: false
  <offline>false</offline>

  -->

  <!-- pluginGroups
   | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e.
   | when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers
   | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.
   |-->
  <pluginGroups>
    <!-- pluginGroup
     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
    -->
  </pluginGroups>

  <!-- proxies
   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
   | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
   | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
   |-->
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
 -->
  </proxies>

  <!-- servers
   | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.
   | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.
   |-->
  <servers>
    <!-- server
     | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a particular server, identified by
     | a unique name within the system (referred to by the 'id' attribute below).
     |
     | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are
     |       used together.
     |
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>repouser</username>
      <password>repopwd</password>
    </server>
    -->

    <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate.
    <server>
      <id>siteServer</id>
      <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>
      <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>
    </server>
 <mirrors>
    <!-- mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
     | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
     | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
     -->
  </mirrors>

 <profiles>

**<profile>
  <id>jboss-amq-maven-repository</id>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-amq-maven-repository</id>
      <url>file:///home/amq-broker/amq-broker-7.5.0.GA-maven-repository/maven-repository</url>  1
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>jboss-amq-maven-repository</id>
      <url>file:///home/amq-broker/amq-broker-7.5.0.GA-maven-repository/maven-repository</url>  2
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</profile>**

    <profile>
      <id>jdk-1.4</id>

      <activation>
        <jdk>1.4</jdk>
      </activation>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jdk14</id>
          <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
          <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
    -->
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>

      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>target-env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>

      <properties>
        <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    -->
  </profiles>


  <activeProfiles>

    **<activeProfile>jboss-amq-maven-repository</activeProfile>**

  </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

***I tried almost everything while trying to solve this problem....but idk what to do anymore.***

*Here's a practical example of whats happening:*

[image]

**And heres my POM.xml from the examples directory**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: run this command and retry `dos2unix -f /home/amq-broker/.m2/settings.xml`

Comment: I got this as response: 
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-parseable settings /home/amq-broker/.m2/settings.xml: in comment after two dashes (--) next character must be > not   (position: START_TAG seen ...</passphrase>\n    </server>\n\n  <!-- ... @133:8)  @ /home/amq-broker/.m2/settings.xml, line 133, column 8

Comment: Why are you taking screenshots of text files instead of just copying and pasting? It makes it very hard to read.

Comment: I can't copy everything directly without having to do it again on my bash, idk why. So copying the pom.xml file would took a time that i dont wanna waste....im kinda in a hurry here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the simplest way to use a custom repository is to specify a custom settings file on the command-line when you execute Maven using the `-s` switch. In your case, you should do the following:

1. Unzip the Red Hat AMQ Maven repository (e.g. `amq-broker-7.5.0-maven-repository.zip`)
2. Modify the `example-settings.xml` in the unzipped files so that the repository `<url>` elements reflect the path to which you've unzipped the archive.
3. Run the example with the `-s` switch for Maven (e.g. `mvn -s /path/to/example-settings.xml verify`)

I just ran through these steps with a default `.m2/settings.xml` and it worked no problem.